# what are advantages and limitations of using mono project to run c# code on linux?

Tags: c#, linux, mono

If anybody having the solution of advantages and limitations of using mono project to run C# Code on Linux, Please tell me your thoughts...

Comment: If C# is the language you are most familiar with, or if you are already starting with a C# codebase, then go for it. Otherwise, I'd recommend Python, which is an easy language to use, has a standard library at least as good as that of C#, and allows for cross-platform GUI programs on Windows or Linux with no modification.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a huge advantage - it works.  You can use C#, develop, and run on Linux (and other platforms, including Windows).

The disadvantage is that things don't always work the same way as they do in MS's .NET implementation, and there is some functionality that is not implemented at all, such as WPF.

Comment: Thanks Reed Copsey,could u please explain little bit more about disadvantage?

Comment: @Saravanan: What do you want to know?  Some functionality just doesn't exist.  It's also a completely different implementation, so things occasionally don't work the same way (though this is rare).  For the most part, "it just works" and is great (as long as you don't use anything that calls into native code), though.

Comment: Another advantage is that you can use the Mono Framework to develop apps that run on windows, mac, and linux. Since it uses visual studio to do development I believe you can also debug the applications remotely

Comment: @kurtnelle: True - provided you buy the Mono for Visual Studio product: http://mono-tools.com/

Comment: okey, i understood.I developed C# windows Form based(desktop) application.Is this work good on linux?

Comment: @Saravanan: Provided you stick to "standard" Windows Forms controls, and use mostly C# 2 features, it should work fine.  Windows Forms is very well supported by Mono.

Comment: @Saravanan, the latest version of mono supports much of .NET 4, as @Reed noted earlier some is missing, but that's rare and some is different since the OSes are different.

Comment: You should switch the framework to Mono 4 to know for sure. If it doesn't compile then the won't work. If it does, then you're good.

Answer (score 4):

**Advantages**

- Investment - when you choose right software you don't have to pay for software licences when running Mono on Linux (this doesn't mean that it's free - Linux is only free if your time has no value).
- No vendor lock-in - you have more choices for other software on Linux (for example DB or Web servers) when compared to MS solutions which works best with other MS stuff.
- Mono specific libraries (for example Mono.Simd or REPL).
- Open source (you, or others, can fix bugs/provide patches/improve code by yourself).

**Limitations**

- Incompatibility with MS.NET framework.
- In general you will probably spent more time with certain things (for example dealing with incompatibility or learning Linux administration and such).
- Mono is not up-to-date with new API and features for some time when new version of .NET framework is released.

Comment: I could call that Partial compatibility between Mono and FCL

Answer (score 3):

I have developed a few apps in C# and have tried to get a few running on Linux via Mono. Getting console applications to run in pretty simple. Most of the time, there is no code change needed to get these types of applications running under Mono. However, GUI applications are always more tricky. The first thing you should know is that your user interface will not blend in with the user's theme. The application will always look like a Windows 98 application, assuming you are using Microsoft's System.Windows.Forms.

If, however, you plan to write and run the application only on Linux, then you could use Mono's Gtk# to build the user interface. This integrates with Linux desktops much better than System.Windows.Forms. [This page](http://www.mono-project.com/Gui_Toolkits) gives a good rundown of the different GUI toolkits, their pros, and their cons.

If you are sticking with System.Windows.Forms for the GUI toolkit in order to run your application on both Windows and Linux, keep in mind that even though Mono supports C# 4.0, you are better off keeping yourself limited to C# 2.0, as some of the features of 3.0 and up aren't implemented or do not work well on Linux.

Comment: Why stick to C# 2? C# 3 support has been solid for years, and C# 4 and the core .NET 4 APIs are done. Note that C# 3.0 was part of .NET 3.5 - the APIs that were added to .NET in 3.0 may not be well supported, but they're pretty much standalone and are not required to use 3.5 or 4.0 features.

Comment: +1 about the warning of non-native GUIs. The best approach is the not directly port the GUI and separate the app logic from the GUI as much as possible.